# Include lines in tangled source code but not in executed code block

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, python

The title might be slightly confusing. What I mean is this. Let's say I have a code block which has some error checking code. If there is an error, the (tangled) program should not continue past that point. Let's say I work with python. If I have a source code like this

```
if len(dummy_list) == 0:
  print("Error!!!")
  sys.exit(0)
```

Executing this in a code block makes EMACS hang. So I don't want this line to be executed in my source block. But I want this line to be present in the tangled source code. Moreover, it would be great if there was a way to destroy the current running session when I counter an error. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you please post a new question about destroying the current session when encountering an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the error checking code in a separate code block with headers set to something like

```el
:tangle myfile.py :eval never
```

This works because code blocks with the same `:tangle` path are concatenated sequentially into the resulting file.  If you are running your Python code in `python` or `ipython` sessions then the evaluations should work even though they are in multiple code blocks.